# Manipulate javascript animation exported from svgator

Tags: svgator

I noticed that there is no programmatic way to manipulate an SVG animation that was exported from SVGator. The official [docs](https://www.svgator.com/help/getting-started/how-to-start-the-animation-on-click) explain how you can start it by a click. But there is no way to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround. You can replace the following code in the svg file

`i=new t(n.animations,n.options);`

with

`i=new t(n.animations,n.options); if (!document.__SVGATOR_) document.__SVGATOR__ = {}; document.__SVGATOR__[n.root] = i;`

then you will be able to stop the animation by doing

`document.__SVGATOR__['id-of-dom-element'].stop()`

Answer (score 0):

You do have the option to export with a "pause" on every second click.

[image: example]